# Toggling with a link with Angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, anchor

I'm trying to toggle a bootstrap well class with AngularJS.
It works fine before I add a controller class but immediately after, the page just redirects to '#'.

Here is my code before a controller is added.

```
<div id="advanced-search">
        <h4><a ng-click="toggle=!toggle" href="">Advanced</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="search-filters" class="well" ng-show="toggle">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Tests</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Certifications</label>
    </div>
```

After Controller

```
<form ng-controller="SearchCtrl" ng-submit="submit()">

    <div class="input-group" id="search-input">
        <input type="text" id="search-bar" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="search-button" type="submit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="advanced-search">
        <h4><a ng-click="toggle = !toggle" href="#">Advanced</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="search-filters" class="well" ng-show="toggle">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Tests</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Certifications</label>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your code with the controller added? (or even better a running example comparing the two)

Comment: as far as I know the controller's functions have nothing to do with it. I believe it may have something to do with the scope after the controller was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Add a value to the 'href' attribute.

```
<a ng-click="toggle=!toggle" href="javascript://">Advanced</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your href:

```
<a ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Advanced</a>
```

Or change it a span:

```
<span ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Advanced</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you written the controller yet? When i pasted your code in plunker it didn't work at first, until i defined your controller and then it started working

http://embed.plnkr.co/lhhkdUEEF17dGpWMqNrd/preview

If you have written the controller, check that it's hooked up right and that there aren't any errors from it in the console that would prevent angular from working.

Answer (score 0):

please try to move ng-controller from FORM tag and place it into a div just above of Form tag, for example :

```
<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
<form>
</form>
</div>
```